# commands not found in centos 6 single mode

Tags: centos

I changed `.bashrc` as a root, and cannot come to a login page in centos 6.7.
Then I decided to use single mode and change the file back.
Then I noticed that I cannot use `ls, rm, mv, vim, vi, more, less or cat` because "`command not found`". I can `cd` and `which`. So how to change content of a file in centos 6.7 single mode？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have wrong **PATH** environment variable value. Try `/usr/bin/vi .bashrc`.